# How to make a method synchronized across all instances of a class

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Today I was asked this interview question and could not answer.
If you have two instances of a Person class which has a setAddress method that is synchronized. Now if it was only one object and multiple threads were accessing it, the `synchronized` will make sure that only one method can access it at a time.

But if there are different objects, one thread will not wait on the other before entering the method.

Now the question is...if I wanted to make the method synchronized across all instances of Person Objects, how do I do that?

Comment: Sounds like a trick question, or I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, or you're not explaining it right. If it's an instance method, then it doesn't matter if there are other instances of that object unless the instance(s) access some shared, mutable, state.

Comment: what about accross EC2 4 instances ?

Comment: @StevenEvers: The existence of that shared mutable state is indeed the reason to implement such a lock or mutex - but that information may have been omitted from the interview question as it's clearly a simplified example. The assumption that the requestion implementation is justified is implicit to an interview question on _how_ to do something.

Answer (score 18):

Synchronize on the Person.class or create a static LOCK object on which you synchronize:

```
synchronized(Person.class){
    //...
}
```

or

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

//...
synchronized(LOCK){
    //...
}
```

Either way, we're using a single (static) lock object instance which is common to all callers. Synchronizing on the class mirrors the default behavior of synchronized `static` methods. But it somewhat exposes the lock, which can be dangerous because for instance, some evil code could synchronize on `Person.class` and never release the lock, and make your code jam up. Keeping a separate private lock is therefore more secure.

Comment: Explain why that works.

Comment: Locking on a private static field is MUCH safer than locking the class itself. Locking the class breaks encapsulation and gives up control of the lock to anything can see the class.

Comment: @Despertar Interesting then that the class is used for synchronizing static methods - e.g. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437620#437821)

Comment: @SteveChambers - this is regarded by some as a design flaw in Java's synchronization system (as is the fact that synchronized instance methods synchronize on the instance); it would have been better if in both cases the methods synchronized on a hidden lock object rather than on the class/owner object, as doing so increases encapsulation, but unfortunately it can no longer be changed without breaking compatibility and there's not enough benefit for anyone to want to do that.  See: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/01/12/if-java-were-designed-today-the-synchronizable-interface/

Comment: @PeriataBreatta Yep, it's also one of the issues with the seamless introduction of value-types in Java, that any Object can suddenly be asked to provide synchronization machinery. Still, back in the early 1990s, this was all considered a leading-edge marvel of cleverness, helping every Object to be an Actor...

Comment: @Despertar That can be either good or bad - it does allow the *caller* to atomically (with respect to the object) call multiple methods: `synchronized(foo) {foo.bar(); foo.baz();}`

Comment: IMO, the first option should be removed since it's a horrific practice.

Comment: Should be "synchronized" instead of "synchronize". Can't edit the answer because it requires at least 6 character changes.

Answer (score 0):

Make the setAddress() method static along with synchronized. Basically, you would be making the setAddress() method global so that only one copy of this method exists and by making synchronized only one thread would be entering this method.

public synchronized static void setAddress(){
    //...
}

There is a drawback: All the instance variables will 've to be made static. As only static variables can be accessed from the static method.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted so harshly.  It's a valid solution to the problem, albeit probably not as good as the existing answer, but the option should be considered.

Comment: This is no valid solution to the problem. And with the last paragraph (which is wrong - passing the Person would make this a horrible workaround at least) it will make the Person class completely useless, as all Persons now share the same data.